# Regarding problem in building Session factory

Tags: java

`

```html
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.074 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.22
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 2 2022 16:53:56 UTC
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.22.0
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.079 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.13+10-LTS-370
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.080 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.106 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.106 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.106 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.106 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.106 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\conf\logging.properties
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|DESKTOP-BBI82LE
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.107 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\temp
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.333 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.33] using APR version [1.7.0].
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.333 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.343 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022]
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.891 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
01-Jul-2022 16:46:59.935 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1225] milliseconds
01-Jul-2022 16:47:00.045 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
01-Jul-2022 16:47:00.045 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.22]
01-Jul-2022 16:47:00.061 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\conf\Catalina\localhost\mycart.xml]
01-Jul-2022 16:47:00.087 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/mycart] in deployment descriptor [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\conf\Catalina\localhost\mycart.xml] has been ignored
01-Jul-2022 16:47:02.383 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
01-Jul-2022 16:47:02.731 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [295] milliseconds.
01-Jul-2022 16:47:02.777 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\conf\Catalina\localhost\mycart.xml] has finished in [2,716] ms
01-Jul-2022 16:47:02.779 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\webapps\docs]
01-Jul-2022 16:47:02.833 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\webapps\docs] has finished in [53] ms
01-Jul-2022 16:47:02.834 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\webapps\examples]
01-Jul-2022 16:47:03.557 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\webapps\examples] has finished in [723] ms
01-Jul-2022 16:47:03.559 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\webapps\host-manager]
01-Jul-2022 16:47:03.635 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [75] ms
01-Jul-2022 16:47:03.635 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\webapps\manager]
01-Jul-2022 16:47:03.715 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\webapps\manager] has finished in [80] ms
01-Jul-2022 16:47:03.716 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\webapps\ROOT]
01-Jul-2022 16:47:03.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [75] ms
01-Jul-2022 16:47:03.800 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
01-Jul-2022 16:47:04.176 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [4240] milliseconds
01-Jul-2022 16:49:37.103 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/mycart]
01-Jul-2022 16:49:37.168 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\conf\Catalina\localhost\mycart.xml]
01-Jul-2022 16:49:37.170 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/mycart] in deployment descriptor [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\conf\Catalina\localhost\mycart.xml] has been ignored
01-Jul-2022 16:49:38.991 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
01-Jul-2022 16:49:38.997 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\apache-tomcat-10.0.22\conf\Catalina\localhost\mycart.xml] has finished in [1,829] ms
01-Jul-2022 16:49:39.004 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mycart]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
01-Jul-2022 16:49:42.716 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 17 and column 27 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'session-factory' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at com.learn.mycart.helper.FactoryProvider.getFactory(FactoryProvider.java:22)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:133)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:380)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:328)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:356)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:867)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1760)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 27; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'session-factory' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:463)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:435)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:127)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 27; cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'session-factory' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:511)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3587)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3472)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3432)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3334)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2372)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:943)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.endElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:584)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.endElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.endElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:81)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.handleEndElement(StAXEventConnector.java:234)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.bridge(StAXEventConnector.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:460)
    ... 36 more
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awHiK.png)

```js
//hibernate_cfg.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>               //this tag is used to configure and initialize the session factory settings for hibernate such as Dialect class and connection Driver class properties
        
        <property name = "connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"</property>
        <property name = "connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mycart</property>
        <property name = "connection.username">root</property>
        <property name = "connection.password">root</property>
        <property name = "dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</property> 
        <property name = "hbm2ddl.auto">update </property>
        <property name = "show_sql"> true</property>/>
        

        
        </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>






  //index.jsp
  
  
  
  <%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : 27-Jun-2022, 9:43:58 AM
    Author     : Pankaj Yadav
--%>

<%@page import="com.learn.mycart.helper.FactoryProvider"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <<h1> Creating session factory object</h1>
        <%
           out.println( FactoryProvider.getFactory());
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
//FactoryProvider.java



package com.learn.mycart.helper;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 *
 * @author Pankaj Yadav
 */
public class FactoryProvider
{
  private static SessionFactory factory;
  
  public static SessionFactory getFactory()
  {
      
      try 
      {
          if(factory == null)
          {
                      factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

          }
      }catch(Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
     return factory;
  }
}






<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : 27-Jun-2022, 9:43:58 AM
    Author     : Pankaj Yadav
--%>

<%@page import="com.learn.mycart.helper.FactoryProvider"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <<h1> Creating session factory object</h1>
        <%
           out.println( FactoryProvider.getFactory());
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
//pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mycart</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
</dependency>




<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.5</version>
</dependency>

        
            
            
            
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`I am makinga an project and in building session factory object I am getting an error called "Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

- with linked exception:"

After running the code we should get the reference hash code for the session factory, and object of session factory implementation class,but I am getting null only. I am attaching the screenshot of the output that I am getting and the correct output. Also, I am sharing the "pom.xml" code, "hibernate.cfg.xml" code and "Factory Provider. java" code and "Indesx.jsp code" module of my project. Please check and do let me know where is the error? Please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAD8k.png)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

- with linked exception:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wh6g.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete exception stack trace from the server log.

Comment: Please check I have attached the screenshot of the error,also I have pasted the outut which I am getting on running the project.

Comment: You don't use `//` for comments in XML: `//this tag is used`

Comment: removed the // also, still not working.

Comment: `<property name = "show_sql"> true</property>/>`

Comment: random `"` in `<property name = "connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"</property>`

Comment: extra space after `update`. You need to pay attention to detail.

Comment: @tgdavies sir I did the same as mentioned by you,now in the output window I am not getting any error or any exception but when running the code in the "edge browser " I am still getting "null" which means that still the session factory object is not created. Please tell what should I do now. This minute error has wasted my 4 days.

Comment: Check the server logs for errors.

Comment: @tgdavies I am unable to figure out what is the problem with the code. Can you please help me by sharing the screen by arranging a virtual meet using the "Cisco Webex" or "Microsoft Teams"? Please it's very important for me.